# couchbase with binary document as value

Tags: nosql, key-value, couchbase

we have heard if we want to save binary data as value to couchbase, it encoded with base64, which expand 30% in size and consume encode decode time. it may not acceptable, any other solutions? eg. modify couchbase to support binary value? thanks

BTW, any description doc on codes?

Comment: You might be happy to know that couchbase compress JSON. Today at disk and in the future all over their system

Answer (score 1):

You can store any kind of value you want in Couchbase. This includes binary documents, JSON documents, etc. The only thing to keep in mind is that we only index JSON documents so you can't query into binary data. Documents are only shown in base64 in the Web UI and may be stored that way on disk, but this should be completely transparent to you. You should not have to worry about anything being in base64 in your application unless of course you do this yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes, we know it is transparent to users, and we want to dive into this, since it is related to performance ( space and time in encode and decode) . we just want to make sure whether it is encoded or not, and any possibility to save binary data (eg. protobuf) without encoding, thanks

Comment: we know that binary data could not been indexed as the value, it is make sense and we don't need to index at this time